# Why isn't there a .getURLs() in ClassLoader?

Tags: java, classloader

In another answer, I wrote the following code (Java 7):

```
public final class Foo
{
    public static void main(final String... args)
    {
        final ClassLoader loader = Foo.class.getClassLoader();

        final URL[] urLs = ((URLClassLoader) loader).getURLs();

        for (final URL url : urLs) {
            System.out.println(url);
            System.out.println(Files.probeContentType(Paths.get(url.toURI())));
        }
    }
}
```

I had to cast the `ClassLoader` to `URLClassLoader` in order to have the `.getURLs()` method.

This is not the first time I've been doing it, and this cast has never failed for me.

Looking at the type hierarchy, I see that:

```
URLClassLoader -> SecureClassLoader -> ClassLoader
```

My question is why doesn't `ClassLoader` define `.getURLs()`? Are there concrete examples of class loaders being unable to return URLs?

Comment: I would think that there are `ClassLoader` classes that load their classes from resources that aren't accessible through URLs.

Comment: As per Oracle docs.... the JVM loads classes from the local file system in a platform-dependent manner. But URLClassLoader - is used to load classes and resources from a search path of URLs.

Comment: @Arjit you _can_ wrap a local file system resource as a URL (`file:...`)

Answer (score 0):

Just search through grepcode. For example JBoss' [ModuleClassLoader](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.jboss.modules/jboss-modules/1.3.0.Beta3/org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader.java?av=h#ModuleClassLoader) does not extend URLClassLoader